# Feedback on solution to $30/(4x+5)=95$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The problem is
$$\frac{30}{4x+5} = 95$$
I multiplied $95$ by $(4x+5)$ and then eventually got:
$$-445 = 380x$$
and dividing by $380$ gives
$x = -1.17$.
Is this correct?

Comment: Just to be sure: you mean $\frac{30}{4x + 5}$ and not $\frac{30}{4x} + 5$? Yes, no, maybe?

Answer (score 2):

**Looks correct to me.**

The reasoning is sound, and if we plug your approximation into the original equation, we obtain:
$$\frac{30}{4*-1.17 + 5} = \frac{30}{0.32} = 93.75$$
which is fairly close to $95$, so this looks pretty good.

If we plug in the exact solution $x = -445/380 = -89/76$, then we get
$$\frac{30}{4*(-89/76) + 5} = \frac{30}{-89/19 + 95/19} = \frac{30 \times 19}{-89 + 95} = 5 \times 19 = 95$$
which is exactly what we want. You’ve rounded correctly, so your solution is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is an approximation to the correct answer of -89/76. If you are looking for an approximation then your answer is fine (to two decimal points) otherwise, reduce the fraction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's correct. The answer is $$x=-\frac{445}{380}=-\frac{89}{76}\approx -1.17.$$